# JavaScript Canvas Animation

Tags: javascript, performance, jquery, canvas

This animation makes my fans spin up after several seconds, and it seems to have a sub-par framerate. I am trying to understand why, and optimize its performance.

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/bVVGLg)

The animation function (this is the main part of the code):

```
function animate() {
    t++
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

    for (var i = 40; i < max; i+= 60) {
        var radius = Math.floor(i+Math.sin(t/10)*10)
        ctx.beginPath()
        ctx.arc(center[0], center[1], radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false)
        ctx.closePath()
        ctx.stroke()
    }

    requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

The `for` loop draws the minimum number of circles needed in order to fill the screen. Their radius pulses in and out with a sine function based on the 't' variable.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Do you suspect something is wrong or are you just looking for general improvements?

Comment: @Mast Thanks! I guess I'm just assuming that it's inefficient because it makes my macbook's fans spin up after maybe 10 seconds, whereas I've seen fullscreen canvas animations/apps that take basically no noticeable toll on my computer.

Answer (score 1):

> I guess I'm just assuming that it's inefficient because it makes my macbook's fans spin up after maybe 10 seconds

That's not really a good measure of "efficiency". The browser is trying to render 60 frames per second. That's a frame every ~16ms. Of course that's going to cause your processor to churn.

```
Math.floor(i+Math.sin(t/10)*10)
```

You can use `<number> | 0` to trim off the decimal places of your numbers. In some JS engines and certain versions of JS engines, bitwise operations are faster than your regular math functions.

```
2 * Math.PI
```

There is a very small penalty when accessing object properties and becomes evident when you use it all over the place. Since `Math.PI` is a constant value, it wouldn't hurt if you assigned it to a variable for direct access. In fact, `2 * Math.PI` is also constant. Why not put the result in a variable and spare the engine a multiplication operation as well.

```
function animate() {
  ...
  requestAnimationFrame(animate)
}
```

The issue with depending on just the render loop is the time it takes between updates. `requestAnimationFrame` can run faster or slower depending on conditions. If your "tweening" is time-sensitive, you might want to update based on [delta-time](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/13008/30967) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I did some research, and after recreating it in a webGL renderer (Pixi.js), it runs without breaking a sweat. I think it's just a limitation of the 2d canvas context…

Comment: @MarcusPlimsoll That's because webgl is hardware accelerated.